# regex check string for various characters followed by any number

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm scanning header rows of files that only have delimiters of pipe, comma, and tilde and ensuring column names do not start with digits.

Take the following variables for easy testing, where I put my regex pattern into its own variable and then create "good" and "bad" header strings:

```
# check if header row has columns that start with numbers
regex="[|~,][[:digit:]]" /* pipe, tilde, or comma followed by any digit */
good_header="col1|col2|col3"
bad_header="col1|2col|col3"
```

I would expect the following to return `good` because there are no column names starting with a digit:

```
if [[ $good_header =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "good"
else
    echo "bad"
fi
```

However, it returns `bad`. Why is this? What's wrong with the logic?

Comment: Your regex isn't quite correct; it won't find `"8col1|col2|col3"`. Change it to `"(^|[|~,])[[:digit:]]"`

Comment: Thanks, @Bohemian. Can you briefly explain with your logic is doing? Also, why doesn't this logic work when I replace `[[:digit:]]` with `\d`?

Comment: Changing `[|~,]` to `(^|[|~,])` added *start of input anchor* `^` as an alternate preceding match - `|` is an OR operator in regex (technically called an *alternation*). Many languages/tools/shell etc, especially bash, don't understand shorthand's like`\d`. `[[:digit:]]` is the posix standard.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it comes back as bad is because your regex is not finding any instances where `$good_header` matches the condition, so it evaluates to false. Switch the logic to:

```
if [[ $good_header =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "bad"
else
    echo "good"
fi
```

Comment: Or your Regex. `regex="[|~,][^[:digit:]]" /* pipe, tilde, or comma not followed by any digit */`

Comment: Been a long day, thanks for clarifying!